# Can I write a Spark UDF to connect to Oracle Database using spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Basically, I need to connect to the Oracle Database from the UDF
(param) -> {

```
                Dataset<Row> df =  spark.read().format("jdbc")
                             .option("driver",driver)
                             .option("url", url).option("user", username)
                             .option("password", password)
                             .option("dbtable", query)
                             .load();
                       String val  = df.select(select fun(param));
                       return val;
    }, DataTypes.StringType);
```

My select query will make a call to the DB function and returns a varchar

Comment: If you have to connect to external source from udf then probably its already a bad design and need to rethink about the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below example if it solves your requirement.

```
val transform: SparkSession => DataFrame = (spark: SparkSession) => spark.read.format("jdbc")
   .option("driver",driver)
   .option("url", url)
   .option("user", username)
   .option("password", password)
   .option("dbtable", "employee.payroll")
   .load()
  transform(spark).select("name").show()

+----+
|name|
+----+
| ROB|
| VAN|
+----+
```

Comment: Hi Ujjal, Here my requirement is UDF should accept a parameter, within the UDF I need to make a call to the DB function by passing the parameter. DB Function should return a varchar

Comment: Hi Venkatt--I think connecting directly to external DB from UDF is not a recommended approach. I was in the impression you are trying to make a JDBC connection directly with spark and wanted that to be part of the UDF call.